# Flex box cuts off long content on ios

Tags: css, flexbox

Using flex to lay out a menu, all works nicely on chrome on windows:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

However on ios devices (various iphones and ipads) the longer content does NOT expand its container as much as it should, and/or the smaller items don't shrink as much as they should, and the longer content gets cut off:

[image: ios screenshot]

I'm viewing on Safari 9, which should be pretty up to date and not need prefixes (I've tried prefixes anyway - they didn't work). Am I missing something?

```
<style>
.lvl1Menu
{
  width:750px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color:white;
  padding:0;
  font-size: 16px;
    flex-direction: row;

}

li{
  list-style: none;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#EEEEEE;
  padding:0px;
  font-size: 25px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;

}

</style>
<ul class="lvl1Menu">
    <li>
        Some words
    </li>
    <li>
        Some words
    </li>
    <li>
        ONELONGWORD
    </li>
    <li>
        Some words
    </li>
    <li>
        Some words
    </li>
    <li>
        Some words
    </li>
    <li>
        Some words
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Update: this bug appears in ios 9, but is fixed in ios 10.

Comment: Have you tried adding *min-width: auto* to the flex items?

Answer (score 3):

"Chrome, Opera, and Safari do not honor the default min-content size of flex items. Set flex-shrink to 0 (instead of the default 1) to avoid unwanted shrinkage."

Source:
https://philipwalton.com/articles/normalizing-cross-browser-flexbox-bugs/

I'm guessing the Chrome has fixed this since then, but Safari hasn't.

Comment: I don't think that applies here as I DO want the flex items to shrink. Without shrinkage the text won't wrap, and the container expand beyond its set width (or wrap, either of which is unwanted). I can add flex-shrink:0 just to the flex item in question, but I don't think that's a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to set `flex-shrink:1;` and possibly `flex-grow:1;`
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-shrink/

Comment: The shorthand flex: 1 1 auto; sets shrink and grow to 1. Also, I tried adding them explicitly and it made no difference.

Comment: Chrome, Opera, and Safari do not honor the default min-content size of flex items. Set flex-shrink to 0 (instead of the default 1) to avoid unwanted shrinkage. source: https://philipwalton.com/articles/normalizing-cross-browser-flexbox-bugs/